# FormObject validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I have form object which is responsible for searching proper cars.

```
class SearchForm
  include Virtus.model
  include ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Model

  validates :handover_location, :return_location, presence: true
  def persisted?
    false
  end

  attribute :car_class, String
  attribute :handover_location, Integer
  attribute :return_location, Integer
  attribute :handover_date, DateTime,
    default: ->(form, attribute) { Time.current }
  attribute :return_date, DateTime,
    default: ->(form, attribute) { form.handover_date + 7.days }
  attribute :car_body_style, Integer
  attribute :car_fuel, Integer
  attribute :car_seats, Integer
  attribute :car_transmission, Integer
  attribute :car_brand, Integer

  def submit
    Car.search({
      handover_date: handover_date,
      return_date: return_date,
      handover_location: handover_location,
      return_location: return_location,
      car_class_id: car_class,
      car_body_style: car_body_style,
      car_fuel: car_fuel,
      car_seats: car_seats,
      car_transmission: car_transmission,
      car_brand: car_brand
    })
  end
end
```

I'm now trying to add validation to this form object. I tried:

```
validates :handover_location, :return_location, presence: true
```

But this not works. Thank's in advance.

Comment: Do you ever call `SearchForm#valid?`?

Comment: Nope... Ok now it's working :) I've think that validation in form object works out of the box like in ActiveRecord models.